# Restarting Primary Key

Tags: postgresql, primary-key-design

**Here is my situation:**

I have a table that gets truncated once a week and new values are placed in it.

**What I want to do:**

I want to add a primary key that starts at 1 and increases by 1 for each row in the table that gets inserted. When the table gets truncated, I want this count to start back at 1.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altersequence.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `serial` column and use the option `restart identity`

```
truncate table foo restart identity
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html